# Can send, but not receive email

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mx-record, email-server, roundcube

I am able to send but not receive email on my server - this is similar to an issue I had before, but I've gotten further along and my emails send without issue.

I believe the email receiving problem is based on my MX record.

My postfix main.cf file looks like this:

```
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = domainname.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = domainname.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhost
name
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
#inet_protocols = ipv4
#virtual_alias_domains =
allow_percent_hack = no
swap_bangpath = no
mydomain = domainname.com
mynetworks_style = host
```

With domainname.com not being my real domain name, but a fake stand-in.

I've got an MX record set that is pointing directly to domainname.com.

I'm seeing a lot of examples with a mail subdomain - is that a requirement? As in, should I do mail.domainname.com as my mx record instead, and setup a subdomain somehow? Or will my current setup work fine?

I just created the MX record perhaps an hour or two ago - how long does it take to propagate?

Are there any other reasons I would be able to send email but not receive? I've checked my mail log, and these are the only messages:

```
Nov  7 18:09:09 domainname postfix/pipe[29051]: 5D2CC120220: to=<myname@domainname.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=2117, delays=2116/0.04/0/0.08, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Nov  7 18:09:09 domainname postfix/pipe[29052]: 6C0F1123722: to=<myname@foodfitnow.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=477, delays=476/0.02/0/0.08, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Nov  7 18:09:09 domainname postfix/pipe[29054]: 976501207F0: to=<myname@domainname.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=990, delays=990/0.03/0/0.06, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Nov  7 18:10:57 domainname postfix/sendmail[29084]: fatal: myname@gmail.com(33): No recipient addresses found in message header
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/qmgr[28334]: B9C071238A6: from=<myname@gmail.com>, size=2448, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/trivial-rewrite[29100]: warning: do not list domain domainname.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/qmgr[28334]: A2D8112388A: from=<myname@domainname.com>, size=583, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/trivial-rewrite[29100]: warning: do not list domain domainname.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/pipe[29104]: A2D8112388A: to=<myname@domainname.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=2387, delays=2387/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Nov  7 18:14:09 domainname postfix/pipe[29103]: B9C071238A6: to=<myname@domainname.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=2370, delays=2370/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

I'm pretty sure I've almost got this - I just need to figure out why my mail server isn't able to receive mail.

Here's the dovecot log... appears to be a permissions issue?

```
Nov 06 05:36:59 imap(andy@domainname.com): Error: user andy@domainname.com: Initialization failed: Namespace '': stat(//var/vmail/vmail1/domainname.com/a/n/d/andy-2014.11.06.01.31.59//Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=2000(<unknown>) egid=2000(<unknown>) missing +x perm: //var/vmail, dir owned by 5000:5000 mode=0700)
Nov 06 05:36:59 imap(andy@domainname.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
Nov 06 05:37:52 auth-worker: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 auth: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 lmtp(671): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 lmtp(672): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 lmtp(669): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 lmtp(670): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:37:52 lmtp(673): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Nov 06 05:38:16 master: Info: Dovecot v2.0.19 starting up (core dumps disabled)
Nov 06 05:38:48 auth-worker: Info: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connected to database vmail
Nov 06 05:38:48 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<andy@domainname.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=3768, secured
Nov 06 05:38:48 imap(andy@domainname.com): Error: chdir(/var/vmail/vmail1/domainname.com/a/n/d/andy-2014.11.06.01.31.59//) failed: Permission denied (euid=2000(<unknown>) egid=2000(<unknown>) missing +x perm: /var/vmail, dir owned by 5000:5000 mode=0700)
```

Comment: The error was caused by Dovecot during delivering email to user mailbox. Please show Dovecot log `/var/log/dovecot.log`

Comment: Done. It appears like it may be a permission issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of `mail_uid`  and `mail_gid`  in your Dovecot config file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`.
They should be set to `uid/gid` of system user `vmail`

**Eg.**

```
$ id vmail
uid=nnn(vmail) gid=nnn(vmail) groups=nnn(vmail)
```

Also the directory `/var/vmail` should be owned by user/group: `vmail:vmail`.

```
$ ls -dl /var/vmail
```

Comment: There was a little bit more configuration issues as well, but I got it working.